# private/public fields in structs.. acting differently

Tags: go

Why can I do this

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    c := Circle{x: 0, y: 0, r: 5}
    fmt.Println(c.r)
}

type Circle struct {
    x float64
    y float64
    r float64
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/0ypcekVDV9

When I can't do the same with a struct in a package?

If I would try to access a struct with a field with lowercase a compiler error is returned..

Answer (score 4):

As already stated, the fields need to be exported to be accessible from another package. See the [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers)

> **Exported identifiers**
>
> An identifier may be exported to permit access to it from another
>   package. An identifier is exported if both:
>
> - the first character of the identifier's name is a Unicode upper case
>     letter (Unicode class "Lu");
> - and the identifier is declared in the
>     package block or it is a field name or method name. All other
>     identifiers are not exported.

If you want to keep the fields private, you need to use accessor (set/get) methods which you can read about [here](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html)

> **Getters**
>
> Go doesn't provide automatic support for getters and setters. There's
>   nothing wrong with providing getters and setters yourself, and it's
>   often appropriate to do so, but it's neither idiomatic nor necessary
>   to put Get into the getter's name. If you have a field called owner
>   (lower case, unexported), the getter method should be called Owner
>   (upper case, exported), not GetOwner. The use of upper-case names for
>   export provides the hook to discriminate the field from the method. A
>   setter function, if needed, will likely be called SetOwner. Both names
>   read well in practice:
>
> ```
> owner := obj.Owner()
> if owner != user {
>     obj.SetOwner(user)
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2):

If the struct is in a different package than the `main` function, then you cannot access the struct's private fields from that main function.

That is what "private" means.